# SignalR System.InvalidOperationException: Buffer length exceeded

Tags: .net, websocket, signalr, .net-4.5, signalr.client

I've got a .NET client calling a method on a hub as follows:

```cs
var competition = hubProxy.Invoke<Competition>("GetCompetition", "Queen's Final 2013").Result;
```

Debugging on Windows 8, I'm getting the following error:

```
20:23:25.0926734 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
20:23:25.3748631 - ... - WS: ws://localhost:59570/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=-Tp4LiB-1w8TjNuw0ilbeMFjw_B8Vl1c31Oni72nbXazWo6qHBSJCRFJU6YD4wJo9dYZ_mb0vNez2hD8JllF0SUXzkhrN4ejcuO1_gBrFrcsK02xJLBnV_z7d774EFlw0&connectionData=[{"Name":"QueensFinalHub"}]
20:23:25.3968761 - ... - ChangeState(Connecting, Connected)
20:23:34.2938036 - ... - WS: OnMessage({})
20:23:35.5546436 - ... - OnError(System.InvalidOperationException: Buffer length exceeded
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ByteBuffer.Append(Byte[] segment)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageReader.<ReadMessageAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.<ProcessWebSocketRequestAsync>d__8.MoveNext())
20:23:35.5576456 - ... - WS: OnClose(False)
20:23:35.5596469 - ... - ChangeState(Connected, Reconnecting)
20:23:35.5616483 - ... - WS: ws://localhost:59570/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=-Tp4LiB-1w8TjNuw0ilbeMFjw_B8Vl1c31Oni72nbXazWo6qHBSJCRFJU6YD4wJo9dYZ_mb0vNez2hD8JllF0SUXzkhrN4ejcuO1_gBrFrcsK02xJLBnV_z7d774EFlw0&connectionData=[{"Name":"QueensFinalHub"}]
20:23:35.5766587 - ... - ChangeState(Reconnecting, Connected)
20:23:44.3054789 - ... - WS: OnMessage({})
```

The response data is quite large, but I don't get this error when I debug on Windows 7 (where I believe the connection uses Server Side Events).

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignalR has sensible default restrictions on message sizes because it's trying to be a real-time messaging framework, not a web services framework. [The default is 64kb](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin45/WebSockets/WebSocketHandler.cs#L22) for [`WebSocketHandler::MaxIncomingMessageSize`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin45/WebSockets/WebSocketHandler.cs#L109) and this is a read-only property.

It seems like you're trying to use SignalR for what should be a basic HTTP GET request. Have you considered just using AJAX against an ASP.NET WebAPI web service for this kind of data exchange instead?

Comment: This is actually a bug that's being fixed. To workaround it, change the transport to server sent events.

Comment: @dfowler how do I go about doing that?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#transport